# How to use Proj4Js with OpenLayers 3

Tags: openlayers

Given the configuration from http://spatialreference.org/

```
Proj4js.defs["EPSG:32632"] = "+proj=utm +zone=32 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs";
```

how do I tell openlayers 3 to use this when doing a transformation of a point

```
var p1 = openLayers.proj.transform([result.Footprint[0][0] + i.easting(), result.Footprint[1][0] + i.northing()], 'EPSG:32632', 'EPSG:3857');
```

Comment: I can see why you are asking this. I have managed to add a projection class to ol3 and load proj4js, but the transform doesn't do anything. I am still getting my head around ol3 (big change, with all the google closure stuff). I will attempt to come back with an answer in a few days.

Comment: I just used proj4js without ol to do the transform and passed the output to ol. Also, proj4js have also changed it seems, when i load it with requirejs the export is just a function that takes the transformation string as argument. New to both things so not sure how it used to be.

Comment: Yes, sure, that works, but be nice to see it integrated into OL3. Yes, OL3 has changed massively architecturally. Looks good, but learning curve coming

Answer (score 3):

OpenLayers 3 is now using Proj4js 2.2, and Proj4js 1.x support is no longer available.

And Proj4js 2.2 is using different projection definitions. Use definitions from http://epsg.io/, for your example that would be http://epsg.io/32632.js